# Появление горизонтального скролла

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, появился горизонтальный отступ, не пойму из-за чего.

```css
head,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.logo {
  padding-left: 150px;
}

.navigation {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding-right: 148px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu li {
  padding-left: 45px;
  color: #ffffff;
  list-style: none;
  opacity: 0.69;
}

.form_template {
  background-color: #9a9a9a;
  height: 713px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.inner {
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.logo1 {
  padding-left: 150px;
}

.title {
  height: 70px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.title:after {
  margin-top: 35px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 74px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
}

.text {
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 45px;
  height: 61px;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 23px;
  max-width: 70%;
}

.download {
  background: none;
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: 135px;
  height: 42px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.free_trial {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 222px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 360px;
  height: 363px;
}

.trial {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  width: 360px;
  height: 54px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
}

.span {
  color: #ff8b38;
}

.form-inner input {
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  width: 285px;
  height: 31px;
}

.form-inner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 360px;
  height: 365px;
  background-color: white;
}

.get_started {
  width: 360px;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #ff9b51;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border: none;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 1400px;
  height: 105px;
  background-color: white;
}

.title1 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 152px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.text1 {
  padding-left: 152px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #86878b;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.wrapper_icons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper_icons img {
  height: 60px;
  width: 45px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.wrapper_inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 22px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 595px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.tabs_inner {
  padding-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 142px;
  margin-top: 22px;
  flex: 0 1 33.333%
}

.tab {
  margin-top: 1px;
  width: 112px;
  height: 112px;
  line-height: 112px;
  background-color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.tab:hover {
  transition: .2s;
  background-color: #ff8b38;
}

.soft_effect {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.soft_effect_inner {
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.title2 {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 344px;
  height: 21px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.text2 {
  width: 476px;
  height: 132px;
  color: #86878b;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.Download1 {
  width: 121px;
  height: 46px;
  background-color: #ff8b38;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.tabs_image {
  height: 253px;
  padding-right: 148px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>AX IT</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AXIT.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/Logo.png">
    </div>
    <nav class="navigation">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Pricing</li>
        <li>Reviews</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Form -->
  <section class="form_template">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="logo1">
        <img src="img/Logo1.png">
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        MODERN AXURE TEMPLATE FOR BEAUTIFUL PROTOTYPES
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo.
      </div>
      <button class="download">
    Download
   </button>
    </div>
    <form class="free_trial">
      <div class="form-inner">
        <p class="trial">Try Your<span class="span">&nbsp;FREE&nbsp;</span>Trial Today</p>

        <input type="text" name="1" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" name="2" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="text" name="3" placeholder="Password">
        <button class="get_started">
          Get started
         </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
  <!-- Media -->
  <section class="social_media">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="wrapper_inner">
        <div class="title1">
          Social Media
        </div>
        <div class="text1">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper_icons">
        <a href=""><img src="img/facebook.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/twitter.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/pinterest.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/google-plus.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/instagram.png"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img/youtube.png"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Tabs -->
  <section class="tabs">
    <div class="tabs_inner">
      <div class="tabs_column">
        <div class="tab">TAB 1</div>
        <div class="tab">TAB 2</div>
        <div class="tab">TAB 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="soft_effect">
      <div class="soft_effect_inner">
        <div class="title2">
          Tabs with soft transitioning effect.
        </div>
        <div class="text2">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet. Proin gravida dolor sit amet lacus accumsan et viverra justo commodo. Proin sodales pulvinar tempor. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes.<br><br>          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean euismod bibendum laoreet.
        </div>
        <button class="Download1">
     Download
    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="tabs_image">
        <img src="img/image_right_u255.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- List section -->
  <section class="list_section">
    list
  </section>
  <!-- Picture section -->
  <section class="picture_section">
    picture
  </section>
  <!-- Awesome -->
  <section class="awesome">
    awesome
  </section>
  <!-- Prices -->
  <section class="prices">
    prices
  </section>
  <!-- Reviews -->
  <section class="reviews">
    reviews
  </section>
  <!-- Design-->
  <section class="design">
    design
  </section>
  <!-- Contact form-->
  <section class="contact_form">
    contact form
  </section>
  <footer class="footer">
    footer
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: удаляйте элементы из верстки (devTools) и смотрите какой блок влияет на горизонтальный скрол

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выражайте опрос правильнее, приходится голову ломать про какой Отступ идет речь.
Чтобы убрать горизонтальный скролл для тега body пропишите в стилях overflow-x: hidden;
http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow

Также позже я заметил эту часть кода. 
Этот padding и создает тот отступ справа!
`.navigation {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding-right: 148px;
}`

Comment: я в начале обычно сбрасываю стили браузера так  *{margin:0; padding:0; box-sizing: border-box;}